# Turn off anti-aliasing for fonts in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, text, fonts, antialiasing

Flash can use 2 types of fonts such that they can be changed at runtime by actionscript.

- **system fonts** - NOT anti-aliased so renders fast
- **embedded fonts** - anti-aliased so renders slow

The problem with "system fonts" is that you can't rotate the text. Can I use embedded fonts AND turn off the anti-aliasing so it renders fast?

Comment: it's really more complicated than that, you can have aa on system fonts and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean setting the [AntiAliasType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/text/AntiAliasType.html) ?

```
textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;
```

Comment: I think "Bitmap fonts" is what I'm looking for.